# hdfs command is deprecated in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2, hadoop-plugins

I am following [this procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/757934/Apache-Hadoop-for-Windows-Platform) ([YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhxWig96dME)).

While executing the command c`:/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/hadoop namenode -format`, I got the error message given below

```
**DEPRECATED:Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFountError**
```

I am using *jdk-6-windows-amd64.exe*.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Don't try to make us read or watch a video to work out what you are doing when you get this error. Please say it in the question.

Comment: I m getting error while executing c:/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/hadoop namenode -format this command ..

Comment: Oh, sorry. How silly of me :/

Comment: The error message doesn't say the `hdfs` command is deprecated. It says using the `hadoop` command to run hdfs commands is deprecated, and to use `hdfs` instead.

Answer (score 1):

use the cmd **c:/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/hdfs** to replace **c:/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/hadoop**

A lot of hdfs cmds are recommended to run with **bin/hdfs** not **bin/hadoop**

Comment: c:/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/hadoop command is working but c:\hadoop-2.3.0\bin>hadoop namenode -format command is not working . Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFountError

Comment: As I am fresher for this hadoop. I am trying to install it . I am getting error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFountError while executing this command c:\hadoop-2.3.0\bin>hadoop namenode -format .

Comment: use **c:/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/hdfs** there is a '\' not '>'

Comment: I ma getting same error during execution of this c:\hadoop-2.3.0\sbin>hadoop fs -mkdir /in

Comment: Anytime it told you the hadoop cmd is DEPRECATED, you replace the cmd with the recommended one.