# Error: Could not find or load main class hadoop

Tags: hadoop

i am trying to make directory in hadoop
`hadoop fs -mkdir /input`

showing me this error

> Error: Could not find or load main class hadoop

Comment: try using 'hdfs dfs -mkdir /input' and see if it works. Make sure you run this command as a hdfs user. The error is because 'hadoop fs' is deprecated.

Comment: thanks for the answer abhinav but when i restart the hadoop this command work but giving warning util.nativecodeloader

Comment: Please paste the screenshot of your command ans output

Comment: Native libraries aren't required to use Hadoop commands. You can ignore that warning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : Could not find or load main class fs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982910/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-fs)