# How to install hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, namenode

I'm trying to get Hadoop running 'Local Mode' on my Windows 10 machine.
When I run the command:

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

I get the following error message, and the folder hadoop which contains hdfs Isn't being created. Why do I get this error?

```
C:\hadoop-2.3.0\bin>hadoop namenode -format
    DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
    Instead use the hdfs command for it.
    18/04/12 01:52:41 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:76)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1324)
    Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
            at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3107)
            at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1873)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:49)
            ... 2 more
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil.terminate(ExitUtil.java:170)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1331)
```

Comment: So did you do as instructed in the error message and tried the `hdfs` command?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek no i didn't ,but which command ?

Comment: @tk421  i use this one :  java version "1.8.0_151"

Comment: Did you see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29094311/6368697 ? So try just `hdfs namenode -format`

Comment: the same error with this command hdfs namenode -format !!

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yeah i saw it, but the problem is not solved yet in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094213/hdfs-command-is-deprecated-in-hadoop/29094311#29094311  !!

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916243/python-hadoop-streaming-on-windows-script-not-a-valid-win32-application you might use a more up-to-date Hadoop version.  2.7 or higher.  2.9.0 is the current stable version and 2.3.0 is at least 4 years old.

Comment: aha oky @tk421 i'll re install the version 2.7.0

Comment: but which version of java is compatible with hadoop 2.7.0  ??